# Android: test the READ_LOGS permission

Tags: android, logging

I want to test the use of the READ_LOGS permission in Android. Can someone please suggest a simple code that reads some low level log requiring the use of this permission ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can study the example of logcat viewer, in that you can trace your logcat and fetch the value which required READ_LOGS permission,

see example [here](http://code.google.com/p/alogcat/source/checkout)